# Using RPI 3 with Carberry as a LIN Master and display data on 7" display

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio, communication, lin-bus

I'm looking at purchasing a Carberry  (expansion board for the Raspberry Pi) to read LIN slave messages and display them on the Raspberry official 7" display. However I'm having trouble determining a few things.

1) Is it the best way to receive the LIN bus onto the RPI using Carberry, or could I just use a standard LIN transceiver?

2) Once I have the LIN bus data being read by the RPI3 , what software could I use to create nice looking interface to display it as usable information (not just a scrolling feed of the bits)?

Comment: Question could be improved by brief description of carberry and LIN.

Comment: Carberry is an expansion board for the Raspberry Pi. Carberry represents the link between car electronics and the Raspberry Pi, which allows the development of end-user applications, such as media centers, vehicle diagnostics, data logging, fleet management, tracking, blackboxes, burglar alarms, carputing, internet, and much more.                                                                                                 
LIN (Local Interconnect Network) is a serial communications technology that was developed for cost-sensitive use areas in the automobile.